# How to know when a Gematria match is meaningful or not

Tags: gematria-numerology

I have been interested in the subject of Gematria for some time, and have found many very interesting matches. For example....

- Yaakov ben Rivka = Yisrael (both 541)
- Shlomo ben Dovid Hamelech = Kohelet (535 and 536, deemed equal).
- Hashem God of Israel = 613. (i.e. Hashem Elokei Yisrael). And we all say that Hashem, Israel and Torah are all one ("Chad Hu") (meaning, the same!).

And quite a bunch of others.

Of course, you also have the famous ones (not my thoughts) such as

- Moshe Rabeinu = 613
- Torah = 611 (and not 613, since it says Torah Tziva Lanu Moshe and Moshe didn't teach the first 2...Hashem did.

HOWEVER, here is my dilemma.

While certainly, you can find a few here and there, in addition to the example of 541 (Yaakov ben Rivka and Yisrael), the sum 541 also equals the following 3,443 verses! Starting with Beraishis, "the tree should make", "to you all", G-d on the 7th", "and man became a soul" (living is the next word since it's Hebrew). Then there are thousands of others. Then there are the words such as "I find" (Matzasi), To Sarah (U'LeSarah"), etc. etc.

So how can one ever know when it is real and meaningful and when it is coincidence. And I refer even to the sages of yesteryear. How, I would love to learn and understanding if an explanation can be given to me. I haven't asked anyone this yet (except someone who didn't really know), so I am eager for an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget כל מצות יהוה=612

Comment: Please explain "meaningful" and "real". All gematriot are real. They're not made up or fake. There are various methods of using gematria. But as long as they are adding the numbers correctly using one of the valid methods, they are certainly real.

Comment: DanF - Thanks! However, that's not really accurate or true. How in the world can you say that the word Torah (which equals 611, the number of commandments taught by Moshe - which indeed is a fabulous match) also has some connection with the word "and she conceived" (VaTahar), or "the nurses" (HaMenakiot), or "and Arpachshad" (VeArpachshad), or any other totally irrelevant word, of which there are always a hundred times more. Why should any significance be given to what might seem like a coincidence that one happened to match with relevance? I'm sure there's an answer. I would like to know it.

Comment: @ReubenBakst At least for 'VaTahar' can also mean 'and it clarifies', meaning Torah removes the level of obscurity in the world 'Olam' which is from 'Helam'. Similarly, 'HaMenakiot' also has a connotation of that which makes clean, like V'nakeh.

Comment: Hey Reuben, a tip for you: if you want someone to receive a notification for a response in comments on a post they didn't write, include their username in your response, preceded by the `@` symbol. I'm not sure if @DanF saw your response. See [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2068/5323) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I once heard from one of the earlier Chasidisher Rebbe's that said that Gematria's need to match in the higher spheres. Then when we bring it down on this world if it doesn't add up, we use different methods like, כולל, אותיות, א"ת ב"ש, etc... to add it up on this world. It is not just a random matching on numbers. Sorry I don't remember a reference. Will try to update when I find the source.

Edit: Here is a quote from R' Yackov Emdin. 
[לחם שמים על פרקי אבות פרק ג משנה י"ח](https://www.sefaria.org/Lechem_Shamayim_on_Pirkei_Avot.3.18.2)

וגימטריאות. שהן פרפראות בלבד. לומר שעם היותן דברים יקרים. ונחשבים כערך הפרפראות שנאכלין לתענוג אל עיקר הסעודה. כי הפרפראות עם חשיבותן (כי על כן נאכלין באחרונה מפני טעמן המשובח ולהשאיר מתיקותן בפה) ונמכרין ביוקר. אין בהן צורך כל כך ואינן שוין לכל נפש. כלחם ומזון העיקריים בעצם וראשונה. כך אלו הידיעות היקרות והמפוארות בערך זה אל גופי תורה. שהן צריכין לכל נפש. ואלו אינן הכרחיים ולא יאותו לכל אדם לדעתם ולהשיגם. ומאן דלא ידע להו נמי גברא רבה מיקרי. כי אם יודע חשבון תקופות ההכרחי המעשי. אע"פ שאינו יודע טעמו ונעדר ממנו ידיעתו העיונית. לא חיסר מעלת חכם סתמי. שהוא היודע בינה לעתים לדעת מה יעשה ישראל. וכן היודע. הלכה בנזיר. סתם נזירות שלשים יום ואינו יודע למוד הגימטריא. יהיה תלתין. אינו מעכב. ונפקא מניה למדחי הא מקמי האי שחייב לטרוח בידיעת גופי הלכות תחלה. אח"כ יבקש לדעת טעמיהם. וכמו שאמרו לגמר אינש והדר לסבר. ולא יעשה את העיקר טפל. וטפל עיקר. וגם יוצא לנו כלל גדול צריך מאד. ומה שהודיעונו בזה ערך גופי התורה לגוף. וגימטריאות לפרפרת. כי ממנו נדע שהגימטריות אע"פ שהן עינים לתורה. מ"מ אינן עיקר כגופי תורה שנמסרו בידי כל אדם מישראל. ***משא"כ גימטריאות לא נמסרו אלא ביד החכמים האמתיים.*** כי יש בהם דרכים לדבר והפכו. ונדרשים לכל חפציהם. מראים פנים לכל צד לטוב ולרע. כענין ענג נגע. בסוד פנים ואחור וחזרת הגלגל. ובכאן הרשת פרושה ליד מעגל. לצוד את הפתאים שראשן סגלגל. וכצבאים הרוקדים כעג"ל. בהמצאת חריפות של הבל לטהר השר"ץ מן התורה. ודורשים מקראות לעצמו בגימטריאות בדויות לפרוק עול תורה ולהתהלל באלילים הרבו פצעי נכשלים והפילו רבים חללים. לצאת מן הדת ולהאמין בפסולים פגרי אדם וישמעאלים ככת הארורה שיצאה מקרבינו מחדש להסית ולהדיח בני ישראל יבחרו להם אלקים חדשים מקרוב באו להאמין בצבי מודח בחלומות והבלים. וגימטריות מבודים בלתי מקובלים. אוי לנפשם המטומאה אותה רע רעה אחר רעה תבוא לרשעים הללו המקוללים. פנים שלא כהלכה בתורה מגלים. כאלו ניתנה התורה ביד כל סכל ונואל. לדרשה בגמטריות עריות לבנות במה לעצמו להקריב עליה לחם מגואל. זאת היתה חטאת הכופרים הראשונים שעסקו בדרשות של דופי. ויחפאו דברים אשר לא כן על ה'. ואין דעת אחת משובשת מכל המינים השונים ומשונים שאינן יכולין להתלות במקראות בארחות עקלקלות. שזו להם מהתלות. ואם הגימטריא מייפה ומוסיף נוי לנוה ויפ"ה בנשי"ם. עיניה ברכות בחשבו"ן. נגד זה הרשעים עושים מהם נזם שוא באף חזיר להוסיף כיעור בעינים תרוטות וכמ"ה המלא עינים שמהם פנים מוריקות. ובעז"ה נראה לענות לכסילים כאולתן. לרצץ מוחם של אותם שרצים להכות על קדקדם. ועיין חבור תה"ק וע"ע חכ"מ שפקרו המינין תשובתן בצדם. וכללו של דבר גימטריא וג"ש דינן שוה. שאין אדם דן אותן מעצמו על מנת לחדש דברים אשר לא שערים אבותינו הקדמונים בעלי הקבלה האמתיים. רק אם לקיים דברי חכמים ומסורת רבותינו. הן זה וזה מותר ויישר כחו. שכר הרבה יטול. בזה האופן רשאי חכם לחפש אחר גימטריא לסמוך עליה דברים ישרים הנאמרים באמת לא לעקל בית הבו"דה ולא לסתור בנין זקנים ולקלקל. ושלא לבדות דבר לחדש דבר מעתה לזלזל בד"ת ראש להקל. כזה ראה וקדש מצוה להביא מן החדש וכל המרבה ה"ז משובח כסף מחירה לא ישקל. וההולך חשכים ומתחכם להמציא גימטריאות לפרוץ גדר ולהסיג גבול עולם ישכנו נחש וכבן מורה יירה או סקול יסקל. לזה היתה כוונת התנא בעצם וראשונה להעיר על זה להסיר המכשלה והמסלה לסקל להודיע נאמנה שאין הגי' עיקריים. ולא יאותו לאורן אלא אותן שזכו וקנו גופי תורה תמלה לא ישאל בעצו יגיד לו המקל. ולברר דברי ולמען הראותך קצת מהתהפכות הגימטריאות. אציגה עמך פה שנים שלשה גרגרים בראש אמי"ר ויהיו לך למופת ולאות על הגאולה והתמורה הבט נא ותראה נפלאות. הנה תורה גי' הוי"ה אלה"י ישרא"ל. וגי' הוי"ה אהי"ה אדנ"י צבאו"ת. נגד זה היא ג"פ גי' סמא"ל לילי"ת. הרי דרך החיים ודרך המות שאמר הכתוב. וכן אמרו החכמים האלהיים מאן דזכי לה סמא דחיי כו'. כי היא להט החרב המתהפכת לשמור את דרך עץ החיים (בל יקרב איש זר לאכול מפרי עץ החיים. וכמ"ש בס"ה) וכן משה גי' א"ל שד"י. וגי' אלהי"ם אחרי"ם. גם שמד"א. תלמוד גי' השכינ"ה. וגי' לילי"ת. כי העוסק בזה ובזו ניצול מזה ומזו ומאלה. ובלבד שיעסוק בה לשמה. כי אז ניצול מן מקוצים ומן הברקנים. שנסבכים בהם בורים ריקנים. שעושים ממנו כנור מנגנים. לשחוק עושים לחם כזבים ומשתה שמרים שמנים השי"ת ברחמיו יאיר עינינו בתורת אמת לאמתה וישים חלקנו עם חכמיה הנאמנים:

Comment: He asked how to know when they're meaningful, not when are they meaningful. Is there anyone today privy to the higher spheres?

Comment: @robev I think I answered correctly. Chazal, Rishonim, et all, knew the gematria is meaningful on the higher realm rather than the coincidence. Regarding your question if there is anyone today who is privy to that info, I cannot comment on that. Chassidus believes in the power of a Tzadik even in our generation.

Comment: So you're saying only gematrias stated by chazal and Rishonim can be known to be meaningful, otherwise only if we know it's meaningful in the higher spheres? Maybe edit that point into your answer as that wasn't clear.

Comment: Can you translate?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Loosely translated, Gematria is only given to true sages. Since it can be interpreted for good and bad. For example Nega and Oneg. Afterwards he goes on a whole rant about Shabsi Tzvi that used Gematarias to decieve people.

Answer (score 1):

Since gematria is an alphanumeric system, it is best used within a mathematical framework within which the results associated with the use of gematria must be consistent. The framework must necessarily include axioms from which we develop definitions, lemmas, theorems, and corollaries. Indeed, the Method of Gematria can be precisely defined as follows:

Let V_1 and V_2 be two verses in the Bible. Let N_1 be the total gematria of a set of words in V_1. Let N_2 be the total gematria of a set of words in V_2. It is possible that V_1 and V_2 are contextually or thematically linked if and only if N_1=N_2.

This definition refers to words or expressions in the verses that are contextual or thematic. By Collins English Dictionary, the context of a word, sentence, or text consists of the words, sentences, or text before and after it which help to make its meaning clear. So once the Method of the Gematria establishes the association (N_1=N_2) between the two verses, V_1 and V_2, then several verses before and after them may need to be consulted for a better understanding of the association. Also, by the same dictionary, in linguistics, the adjective thematic denotes a word that is the theme of a sentence. In grammar, it is of or relating to the stem or root of a word. Very often, there is a need to consult Strong’s Concordance and the Hebrew and Greek lexicons to fully understand the association between words that are thematic in the Bible.

I am happy to expound further.

Answer (score -2):

Easy:

None of them are meaningful.

This isn't a question of faith, but a question of mathematics. Simply put, for every "good" gimatriya, you can also likely find one with an opposite "meaning".

613 may be the number you get for משה רבינו, but is also the number you get for מכונת כביסה and חטא משכב זכור. Of course, you could also spell it משה רבנו, and then none of these would work any more.

So, while gimatriya may an fun numerical exercise, ascribing any meaning to it would probably not be a good idea.

Comment: There are meaningful gematrias used by chazal and Rishonim. It sounds like the OP wants to know how did they know their gematria was meaningful and not coincidence.

Comment: Re your last paragraph - Absolutely not true. Numerous customs that have abounded for many years resulted from gematria. One I can think o fis the custom not to eat nuts during the 10 days of *teshuva* because the Hebrew word *egoz* and *chet* approx. have the same gematriah. I'm sure that someone has made up a good as well as a bad gematria that has your name on (in) it. People have been doing that with just about everyone's name, for years. I would pay attention to them as they could be useful.

Comment: @DanF - What you are saying, is that since, you, without any evidence, believe these customs to be based on truth, you choose to believe that gematrias are true.

Comment: @nbubis I intrinsically believe and have full faith in everything a notable rabbi says. Every rabbi mentioned in the Talmud or other holy work such as *Shulchan Aruch* fits this category. That's not to say that there are differences of opinion, but those are recorded, as well. However, not being anywhere close to as knowledgable or on the level of righteousness or observance of any of these rabbis, I would have absolutely no reason to deny the truth of what any of them have said. I do not need any "evidence" of their truth, b/c I have insufficient knowledge to deny or debate it.

Comment: @nbubis The Mishna in Avot (3:18) validates the use of "gematria" as פַּרְפְּרָאוֹת לַחָכְמָה. Do you dispute the words of the Mishna?

Comment: "פרפראות" is desert. That Misnha says that Gematria is "desert - after wisdom" - and not a replacement for wisdom...